# How to recode this string variable into a new variable?

Tags: sorting, replace, stata, recode

I want to recode my variable `Ucod` in Stata with >100000 different observations into 3-4 classified values in the form of a new variable.

The problem is that I don't want to enter all the values of `Ucod` to recode. For example I want to use an `if` condition like if any value in `Ucod` starts with `I` (e.g, `I234`, `I345`, `I587`) recode the whole value to `CVD`.

I have tried using `strpos()` function using different conditions but I was unsuccessful.

Attaching picture of my data and variable `Ucod`
[image: View of my data set]

Comment: Could you list all the conditions you want to code? Do they all depend on the initial letter of `ucod`?

Comment: @Stuart thankyou for your reply. These are few conditions. For example: I want to recode Ucod= I00/I519 as "CVD" and I600/I698 as "Stroke".

Comment: Are they all in the format letter followed by 2-3 digit number?

Comment: @Stuart YES, each letter follow 2-3 digit number

Comment: If all conditions are in alphanumeric order, then this answer shows how this can be done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72220773/string-search-for-range-of-icd-codes/72221380#72221380

Comment: Please see the `stata` tag wiki for advice on posting Stata questions, which includes advice not to use screenshots and to use `dataex`.

Comment: @Stuart thanks for your answer. Ucod are ICD-10 codes, they originally comes in this format i.e, "A00.0" . Since data I got doesn't show/have decimal, it is difficult to use code you gave. This code {"ucod_category = 1 if ucod >= "I600"(i.e,which actually is 160.0) & ucod <= "I698"} will miss ''I60'' to include in stroke, which is actually is part of stroke. Is there way we can first convert this alphanumeric "Ucod" with a decimal place after every two number and then use the code which you have given. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Okay, I have edited my answer. The first solution already worked, but you just need to ensure you use the right minimum values. The second solution needed some adjustment to handle the decimal points.

Comment: @Stuart the updated code you shared is returning with this error:
unknown function ascii ( )
r(133);

Comment: @Stuart these are the errors I am getting. Thankyou for your help till now. Really appreciate it

`gen ucod_letter_code = -1

. 
. forvalues i=0/26 {
  2. 
.      replace ucod_letter_code = i if substr(ucod, 1) == char(i) + 65
  3. 
. }
i ambiguous abbreviation
r(111);

. 
. gen ucod_numeric = ucod_letter_code * 1000 + real(substr(ucod, 1)) / cond(strlen(ucod) == 4, 10, 1)
invalid syntax
r(198);

. 
. recode ucod_numeric (800/851.9=0 "CVD") (860/869.8=1 "Stroke"), generate(ucod_category)
variable ucod_numeric not found
r(111);

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use `gen` and a series of `replace` commands:

```
gen ucod_category = 0 if ucod >= "I00" & ucod <= "I519"
replace ucod_category = 1 if ucod >= "I60" & ucod <= "I698"
```

Then label these categories as CVD, Stroke, etc. This should sort in the expected way for your I10 codes with missing decimal points (e.g. "I519" < "I60").

However it might be more convenient to convert `ucod` into a number (with first digit 0 for A, 1 for B etc.) so that you can recode it with labels in a single command:

```
gen ucod_numeric = (ascii(substr(ucod, 0, 1)) - 65) * 1000 + real(substr(ucod, 1)) / cond(strlen(ucod) == 4, 10, 1)
recode ucod_numeric (800/851.9=0 "CVD") (860/869.8=1 "Stroke"), generate(ucod_category)
```

Again, this should sort in the expected order: I519 (which becomes 851.9) < I60 (860).

EDIT: since `ascii` isn't working (possibly a Stata version issue) you can try something like this to change the letter to a number.

```
gen ucod_letter_code = -1
forvalues i = 0/25 {
     replace ucod_letter_code = `i' if substr(ucod, 1) == char(`i' + 65)
}
gen ucod_numeric = ucod_letter_code * 1000 + real(substr(ucod, 1)) / cond(strlen(ucod) == 4, 10, 1)
recode ucod_numeric (800/851.9=0 "CVD") (860/869.8=1 "Stroke"), generate(ucod_category)
```

Comment: You can also use `inrange(ucod, "I00", "I519")` and so on.

Comment: @Stuart these are errors coming up

`gen ucod_letter_code = -1

. 
. forvalues i=0/26 {
  2. 
.      replace ucod_letter_code = i if substr(ucod, 1) == char(i) + 65
  3. 
. }
i ambiguous abbreviation
r(111);

. 
. gen ucod_numeric = ucod_letter_code * 1000 + real(substr(ucod, 1)) / cond(strlen(ucod) == 4, 10, 1)
invalid syntax
r(198);

. 
. recode ucod_numeric (800/851.9=0 "CVD") (860/869.8=1 "Stroke"), generate(ucod_category)
variable ucod_numeric not found
r(111);

`

Comment: corrected an error - please try now

Comment: Thank you for your help @Stuart. I have also came across this code which also worked in adding decimal to my alpha numeric values:
`gen icd_new=ucod
replace icd_new=substr(icd_new,1,3)+"."+substr(icd_new,4,1 )
`