# How to ADD decimal to alpha-numeric variable values?

Tags: string, stata, alphanumeric, recode

I want to add decimal to alpha numeric values of my variable `ucod`. UCOD values are as follows:
I want to add decimal point after 2 digits in a 3 digit alpha-numeric values. Kindly help whether it is possible to do this.
ucod

- .B182 >>>B18.2
- .I251 >>>I25.1
- .F03 >>>F03
- .C55 >>>C55
- .J449 >>>J44.9
- .N390 >>>N39.0

Comment: Please always provide example data using `dataex`. Install using `ssc install dataex` and then see `help dataex`.

Comment: Please respond to the answer provided at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74275321/how-to-recode-this-string-variable-into-a-new-variable

Comment: I suspect the leading dot or period is spurious.

Comment: This was answered. Please indicate whether the answer was helpful, or else why not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all values are exactly EITHER one letter followed by two digits OR one letter followed by three digits, and only the latter should have a decimal point after the first two digits, then this code will work for you:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input str6 varA
".B182"
".I251"
".F03" 
".C55" 
".J449"
".N390"
end

* Remove leading decimal point
gen varB = substr(varA,2,.)

* If string length is 4, take the first 3 charachters, then add a decimal,
* and then add the remaining part of the string and 
* then replace the value with the results
replace varB = substr(varB,1,3) + "." + substr(varB,4,.) if strlen(varB) == 4
```